# Any suggestion for solving linear equations with two unknown to be assumed?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a "linearized" linear-system-of-equations, which requires two parameters to be estimated by iteration because of linearization. The actual problem is nonlinear actually, but using fourier series method, it iss linearized.

I have been solving linear system by just matrices and SVDs which takes not much time but these matrices depend on the two parameters that are to be iteratively solved. At the end I just need to make sure that one of the parameters I solve iteratively matches the response I get in the system. This is the criteria to be minimized.

I have been using "fmincon" and "multi-start" to solve for two parameters and I get some results, but it is taking longer than what I expect. There is local minima issue too, so I had to include "multi-start".

Anyone has an idea if any other method would be easier to solve this problem?

I really appreciate it.

Comment: Any other method? `fmincon` uses a set of quite complex matematical optimization methods. What do you want to improve?

Comment: I bet it is complex but I am not sure what is going on inside. fmincon has a local minimum issue and that's why I am running multi-start to find global minimum. And that's taking very long time... Any suggestions about it?

Comment: No there are no suggestions. This is a open problem in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ander. I just manually ran monte carlo sim and plotted how the error changes with respect to input variables to be iteratively obtained. I realized that there are tons of local minima in the response and that's why fmincon was not able to solve itself and I needed a very refined multi-start for fmincon so that I could get global minimum. This is very interesting observation. Is there any solver that you know of to get the global minimum in cases where there are many local minima?

Answer (score 0):

A global optimization method that one may use is Simulated annealing.
May be MATLAB has a relevant routine.
There is free Simulated annealing software that you may also try.

Answer (score -1):

I got an improvement in my problem, and I just replied it in comments but I think it is worth putting it in here since what I did emerged something unexpected:

So I ran a monte carlo sim for two variables to be iteratively solved, and plotted how the error changes with respect to input variables. I realized that there are tons of local minima in the error of the response and that's why fmincon was not able to solve itself because it was quickly jumping into one of those local minima holes, and I needed a very refined multi-start for fmincon so that I could get global minimum. This is very interesting observation because I wasn't expecting that rough error distribution with respect to two parameters.

Is there any efficient solver/optimizer in matlab that you know of, to get the global minimum in cases where there are many local minima? Or any other method?

Thanks,